# How to replace a set of JSON keys using JMESPath

Tags: json

I have a JSON file that contains the following:

```
{
  "aaa": 5,
  "bbb": 41,
  "Date": "2024-02-29T16:00:33.994Z",
  "ccc": 1,
  "ddd": 1,
  "contents": {
        "aaa": "Order1",
        "Prop_201": 788,
        "Prop_202": 839
  }}
```

And I want to get a json file as an output that contains almost the same, but removing from the keys that has the value Prop_NNN the first part until the underscore, so if a key is the following "Prop_201" I want to convert it into "201".
Notice that I can have several properties in this format, not only two as I am showing in the sample, so the JMESpath must iterate along all of them. The file that I expect as a result of the sample is the following:

```
{
  "aaa": 5,
  "bbb": 41,
  "Date": "2024-02-29T16:00:33.994Z",
  "ccc": 1,
  "ddd": 1,
  "contents": {
        "aaa": "Order1",
        "201": 788,
        "202": 839
  }}
```

Thanks